# how to identify similar string via keywords

Tags: php, regex, string

> **keywords:** all the words with more than 3 characters

I want to compare keywords between two string with these conditions:

1. Moving words does not matter *(example1 is for this case)*
2. Words less than 3 characters are not calculated *(example2 is for this case)*
3. Put shorter sentence in str1 (the number of characters). *(example3 is for this case)*
4. I just want different words in the str1 compared with the str2. *(example4 is for this case)*

In fact i have a robot that attacks on two news website daily and copy the news to my database. Then i need an algorithm to compare news title and identifies duplicate news. (As you know, the same news have different title from different news website. But often, the title of same news are included same keywords)

**example1:**
Moving words does not matter

```
str1= 'hello petter'
str2= 'petter hello'

result: 0
```

**example2:**
Words less than 3 characters are not calculated

```
str1= 'hello !!'
str2= 'petter hello'

result: 0 // '!!' are less than 3characters and str1 is 'hello'. then result:0
```

OR

```
str1= 'hello petter‌ how are u?'
str2= 'petter hello how are you'

result: 0 // str1 is 'hello petter how are'
```

**example3:**
The variables must be changed

```
str1= 'hello petter‌ how are you ?'
str2= 'petter hello how are you?'
// Then
str1= 'hello petter‌ how are you?'
str2= 'petter hello how are you ?'

result:1 // 1 is for 'you' (in str1)
```

**example4:**
Different words are not important in the str2

```
str1= 'hello petter‌ how are you?'
str2= 'petter hello how are you ?'

result: 1 // str2 is 'petter hello how are you', then 1 is for: 'you?' (in str1)
```

> **Note:** 'you' (in str2) is not important for me, because it isn't match
>   with any words of str1.

**expletive example:** *(for more information)*

```
str1= 'petter‌ hello how are you pal?'
str2= 'petter hello how are... !!'

// In first str1 change with str2
str1= 'petter hello how are... !!'
str2= 'petter‌ hello how are you pal?'

// Then remove '!!' (in str1)
str1= 'petter hello how are...'
str2= 'petter‌ hello how are you pal?'

result: 1 // 1 for 'are...' (in str1) - ['are','you','pal?' does not matter (in str2)]
```

Finally, i need a function to identify duplicate news via result and the number of keywords *(all the words with more than 3 character)*.

```
$keywords_numb=7;
$result=2;

function identify_duplicate($keywords_numb,$result){
    if($keywords_numb / 3 >= $result){
        $Specified = 'this is a new news';
    }

    else $Specified = 'this is a duplicate news';
        return $Specified;

}

    echo $Specified;
```

output:

```
this is a new news
```

Anybody know how do i write this program? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of *@karthik manchala*, I did it ...

```
   $str1='this news is about a player named Ronaldo';
   $str2='The player who called Ronaldo';

 function identify_duplicate($str1, $str2){
   if(strlen($str1)>strlen($str2)){
       list($str1, $str2) = array($str2, $str1); // swap two variables
   }

   $str1 = explode(" ", $str1);
   $str2 = explode(" ", $str2);

    $words_numb = sizeof($str1);
    $result=$words_numb;

    foreach($str1 as $val){
     if(in_array($val, $str2) || strlen($val) <= 3){
         $result--;
     }
  }

   if($words_numb / 3 >=$result){
        $Specified = 'this is a duplicate news';
       }
    else $Specified = 'this is a new news';
        return $Specified;
}


$out=identify_duplicate($str1, $str2);
echo $out;
```

**Output:**

> this is a duplicate news

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this.. you can use the following function and pass strings in any order:

```
function identify_duplicate($var1, $var2){
   if(strlen($var1)>=strlen($var2)){
       $str1 = $var1;
       $str2 = $var2;
   }
   else{
       $str1 = $var2;
       $str2 = $var1;
   }
   $str1 = explode(" ", $str1);
   $str2 = explode(" ", $str2);

  $return = sizeof($str1);

  foreach($str1 as $val){
     if(in_array($val, $str2) || strlen($val) <= 3){
         $return = $return - 1;
     }
  }

   return $return;
}
```

Comment: To not depend on the order of variables take longer string as str1

Comment: That is great ! I thought the answer is much longer.  Thank you

Comment: One problem is here, you did not specify keywords (the words with equal or more that 3 character) !!

Comment: WOW !!! How do you find solution so fast ? I wanted to write a function for this episode (specify keywords). anyway thanks !! may you tell me what is your job ?

Comment: Happy to help.. and I am a programmer :)